# Computing $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$ without using independence

Tags: probability, independence

> A person chooses a letter at random from the word RESERVE and then chooses one at random from the word VERTICAL. What is the probability that the same
>   letter is chosen?

This is easy to compute using independence, but the book gives the problem before defining independent events - that is the following chapter. If $R_1=$"R is chosen from RESERVE" and $R_2$="R is chosen from VERTICAL," how to compute $\mathbb{P}(R_1\cap R_2)$ without using independence?

Comment: Can you use the usual Laplace rule of favourable cases divided by possible cases?

Comment: That is covered in the chapter, but I'm unclear on how to use it since we are choosing from two different samples.

Comment: @PenasRaul : for that he still needs the two draws to be independant from each other, so that (S;V) has the same odds as (V;T).

Comment: @IcedPalmer : In case the two draws are not independant, and you don't know their conjoint law, you cannot answer the question. But since it seems to be a not-to-advanced exercise for probability, I'm pretty sure the author implicitely supposed the two draws to be independant.

Comment: The draws shouldn't depend on each other, but at this point "independence" has not been defined in the text.

Comment: I think it is implied in the context that the probability of taking the 2nd letter in REVERSE and the 3rd letter in vertical has the same probability as taking the 4th letter in REVERSE and the 5th letter in VERTICAL. Using that you can apply directly the rule. Notice how I didn't even thought about independence.
 
If that is not implied I don't see anything else, but it's quite natural that the author tries to appeal more to the intuition in the early chapters.

Comment: If the text has not introduce the concept about independence yet and still remain in simple combinatoric model, then it maybe forcing you to use the notion of "Rule of product" in combinatoric. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product
As other said, this is an implicit independence assumption inside and later it will be generalized in more sophisticated model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the book has already used the concept of equally probable events and counting methods of probability, for example saying the probability of choosing E from RESERVE is $\frac{3}{7}$

So here there are $7$ letters in RESERVE and $8$ letters in VERTICAL, giving $7\times8=56$ ways of choosing a letter from each.  You can find that $6$ of these give the same letter, and so the expected answer may be $\frac{6}{56}$ or $\frac3{28}$.

```
        R   E   S   E   R   V   E

V       .   .   .   .   .   V   .
E       .   E   .   E   .   .   E
R       R   .   .   .   R   .   .
T       .   .   .   .   .   .   .
I       .   .   .   .   .   .   .
C       .   .   .   .   .   .   .
A       .   .   .   .   .   .   .
L       .   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

This answer relies on some implicit independence, even if the book introduces the ideas of dependence and independence later